# Scala convert from list to map by property with sum logic

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm new to Scala, trying to convert from list to map with some sum logic as in the following.

```
case class ProductProperty(name:String, value:Option[String]= None, options:List[OptionItem]=List())

case class OptionItem(title:Option[String], description:Option[String] = None , price:Int)

val properties = List(ProductProperty(name = "size", value = Some("val1") , options =  Some(List(OptionItem(price = 10) , OptionItem(price = 204))),
         ProductProperty(name = "size", value = Some("val2") , options = Some(List(OptionItem(price = 122) , OptionItem(price = 240))),
         ProductProperty(name = "color", value = Some("val3") , options = Some(List(OptionItem(price = 101) , OptionItem(price = 204))),
         ProductProperty(name = "color", value = Some("val13") , options = Some(List(OptionItem(price = 102) , OptionItem(price = 120))),
         ProductProperty(name = "Quantity", value = Some("ssval3") , options = Some(List(OptionItem(price = 1011) , OptionItem(price = 204))),
         ProductProperty(name = "Quantity", value = Some("ssval13") , options = Some(List(OptionItem(price = 1102) , OptionItem(price = 1210))
     )
```

I need to flatten it and create new map based on their name with calculated price.

```
Map {
     "size" -> total price,
     "color" -> total price,
     "Quantity" -> total price
}
```

What I've tried so far:

```
val optList =   properties.map( list =>
      list.map(op => op.options
        .flatMap(i => List(ProductProperty(name = op.name, value = Some(i.value)))))
        .flatten
    )

val totalPrice = price.add(optList.map(list =>
      list.map(_.options)
        .flatten.map(_.price.getOrElse(0)).sum)
      .getOrElse(0))
    
Map((optList.map(_.name).getOrElse(List())) -> totalPrice)
```

But it is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is to correct the sample data so that it compiles.

```
case class OptionItem(title       :Option[String] = None
                     ,description :Option[String] = None
                     ,price       :Int)

case class ProductProperty(name    :String
                          ,value   :Option[String] = None
                          ,options :List[OptionItem] = List())

val properties =
  List(ProductProperty("size", Some("val1"), List(OptionItem(price = 10), OptionItem(price = 204)))
      ,ProductProperty("size", Some("val2"), List(OptionItem(price = 122), OptionItem(price = 240)))
      ,ProductProperty("color", Some("val3"), List(OptionItem(price = 101), OptionItem(price = 204)))
      ,ProductProperty("color", Some("val13"), List(OptionItem(price = 102), OptionItem(price = 120)))
      ,ProductProperty("Quantity", Some("ssval3"), List(OptionItem(price = 1011), OptionItem(price = 204)))
      ,ProductProperty("Quantity", Some("ssval13"), List(OptionItem(price = 1102), OptionItem(price = 1210))))
```

After that it's a simple matter of applying `groupBy()`, `map()`, and `fold()` or `reduce()`. Scala 2.13.x offers all 3 at once.

```
properties.groupMapReduce(_.name)(_.options.map(_.price).sum)(_+_)
//res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(size -> 576, color -> 527, Quantity -> 3527)
```

---

For older Scala versions you have to break it up into smaller steps.

```
properties.groupBy(_.name)
          .map{case (k,v) => k -> v.map(_.options.map(_.price).sum).sum}
```

Comment: Im on scala version 2.12 :)

Comment: thanks , and if in future don't need use k at all (will build key from values). properties.groupBy(_.name)
          .mapValues{case (v) => v.toStirng -> v.map(_.options.map(_.price).sum).sum}

Comment: `mapValues()` has been deprecated in current Scala versions. It has some curious side effects. That's why I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing jwvh answer, you can use **cats** *(also in `2.12`)* to simplify the code a little:

```scala
import cats.syntax.all._

val result = properties.foldMap {
  case ProductProperty(name, _, options) =>
    Map(name -> options.foldMap(_.price))
}
// result: Map[String,Int] = Map(size -> 576, color -> 527, Quantity -> 3527)
```

The trick here is that `foldMap` merges a `map` and a `foldLeft` into a single step; so `options.foldMap(_.price)` is essentially the same as `options.map(_.price).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)`

But, the most interesting part is the `properties.foldMap` this because the `Monoid` for `Maps` basically merges two maps together and when they have the same keys it simply combine its values together.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/G1acf9EwRsanFRzZottLiA/1)*.